# Export all old Entries of ldif Files from server with ldaptool and reimport them

Tags: ldap, ldap-query, ldif

I tried to export all Entries that be already imported with ldaptools and i used this

```
.\ldapsearch.exe -x -c -h example -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w secret -b "example"  > output_file.ldif
```

But i did not get the same order especially some Entries were with "add: uniqueMember"

Any tips to export them to get the same as orginal files.

Answer (score 1):

The LDAP (protocol) does not ensure the order of returned Attribute or Values.
There is nothing in LDAP that will help.

You would have to order them on your client.